# What are the best approches for generating random strings from a set of allowed characters?

Tags: javascript, string, random

I have a very simple javascript program which involves generating random strings of characters from a given set of allowed characters.

Generating random strings from a regular expression with [randexp.js](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js?) seems to be the most appropriate way to do so. However, since the set of allowed characters is a very simple one (basically all uppercase characters from the English alphabet and all digits) I wonder if loading an entire library isn't a bit overkill for such purpose. Instead I'm doing something like the following:

```js
const chars = ["A", "B", "C", "D", ...];

let random = () => { return chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)] };
```

Is there something really bad about this (besides being a bit bulky and awkward) or is this ok in this specific case? What would the best approach for generating random string from a set of allowed characters be?

Comment: Depending on what you're using it for: `Math.random()` is not suitable for anything even distantly related to security or secrets.

Comment: @zerkms I should point out my program is not related to security in any way. Thank you for the observation!

Comment: Just in case anyone wants to take a look at the actual code and what it is generating those strings for, it can be accessed [here](https://github.com/GarkGarcia/HackerScreen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is arguably a great use case for [randexp.js](https://fent.github.io/randexp.js/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js/)), a JavaScript library that generates random strings based on regex patterns. It is very powerful and can be used for all sorts of things.

```js
let randexp = new RandExp(/[A-D]{1,5}/);
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    console.log(randexp .gen());

//random numbers
console.log(new RandExp(/[1-6]/).gen());
//words with optional parts
console.log(new RandExp(/great|good( job)?|excellent/).gen());
//wildcard gen: eg. keys
console.log(new RandExp(/random stuff: .{8,20}/).gen());
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/fent/randexp.js/releases/download/v0.4.3/randexp.min.js"></script>
```

Usually, get it via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/randexp) or download a [release version](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js/releases).